# Opening bluetooth settings page and returning to application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin cross-platform application. In which i have to open Bluetooth setting page of my xamarin cross-platform Android application via clicking on a button created.

As soon as the settings open i need to pair device similar to paring in the normal device.

If i click the back button it should return back to my created application.

I have created the following code in my xamarin.form page:

Bluetooth.xaml.cs:

```
using Android.Content;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;// Does not accept this in xamarin forms
using Android.Support.V7.App;// Does not accept this in xamarin forms


private void OnSettingsDevice_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();    
       intentOpenBluetoothSettings.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionBluetoothSettings);
       StartActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
    }
```

It throws an error stating

> The name 'StartActivity' does not exist in the current context.

I even wrote this code in mainactivity.cs which stored in my App.Droid application. I am unable to call this in my xamarin form page.

Even tried with creating a function for this code and call that function in my Xamarin.forms.cs file as well.

Tried with https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2018/12/16/how-to-detect-nearby-bluetooth-devices-with-net-and-xamarin-android/ Blog but could not execute it.

Please help me out with this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: to execute platform specific code from your Forms app, use `DependencyService`

Comment: Assuming that you're already using `DependencyService`, have you tried to use `StartActivity` explicitly in your `App.Droid` ? Like this: `Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);`